# updating multidimensional array sql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am building a recipe website, where recipes are stored in one table, ingredients in another, and then a third table linking the two with the amount and unit of the ingredient.
ie.
Recipe table - Recipe ID, Name, Description etc etc

Ingredient Table - IngredientID, Name, Description etc etc

Recipe Ingredients Table- RecipeIngredient ID, Recipe ID, Ingredient ID, Quantity, Unit

So for one recipe, there can me multiple ingredients. To display recipes, I query the recipe_ingredient table for the matching recipeID, and then get the corresponding ingredientID from this and query the ingredients table for each one:

```
 <table id="ingredients_table">
                        <tr>
                        <th>Ingredient</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                        </tr>
                    <?php 
                        foreach ($ingredient as $value) { 
                            $ingredient_name = get_ingredient_name($value['IngredientID']);
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'.$ingredient_name.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$value['Quantity'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$value['Unit'].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$value['Comments'].'</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo "\n";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </table>
```

where I have the following functions

```
function get_ingredients($id) {
//gets the ingredient ids, quanitites, units and comments
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `recipe ingredients` WHERE RecipeID = $id") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$array = array();

    while($row_ids = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $array[] = $row_ids;
    }   
return $array;
}

function get_ingredient_name($id) {
//get an ingredient name given its ID
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ingredients` WHERE IngredientID = $id") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$ingredient_name = $row['Ingredient'];
return $ingredient_name;

}
```

The problem is I am having trouble creating a form that will update the ingredients quantities or name.

I currently have this but it does not work:

`function update_ingredients($Ingredient_ID, $id, $RecipeIngredientID, $Ingredient, $Quantity, $Unit, $Comment) {`

```
$ingredient_name = mysql_query("UPDATE `ingredients` SET Ingredient='$Ingredient' WHERE IngredientID='$IngredientID'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$ingredient_details = mysql_query("UPDATE `recipe ingredients` SET Quantity='$Quantity', Unit='$Unit', Comment='$Comment' WHERE RecipeIngredientID='$RecipeIngredientID'") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

}
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['RecipeName'])) {
                            foreach ($ingredient as $value) { 
                            $ingredient_name = get_ingredient_name($value['IngredientID']);
                            $Ingredient = userData($_POST['Ingredient']);
                            $Quantity = userData($_POST['Quantity']);
                            $Unit = userData($_POST['Unit']); 
                            $Comment = userData($_POST['Comment']);
                            $update_ingredients =  update_ingredients($Ingredient_ID, $id, $RecipeIngredientID, $Ingredient, $Quantity, $Unit, $Comment);
                            echo $update_ingredients;

                        }
```

can anyone help!

Comment: Have you noticed that `$Ingredient_ID`, `$id` and `$RecipeIngredientID` are not defined into the foreach loop? Are they global?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code instead current:

```
function update_ingredients($Ingredient_ID, $id, $RecipeIngredientID, $Ingredient, $Quantity, $Unit, $Comment) 
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE `ingredients` SET Ingredient='$Ingredient' WHERE IngredientID='$Ingredient_ID'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE `recipe ingredients` SET Quantity='$Quantity', Unit='$Unit', Comment='$Comment' WHERE RecipeIngredientID='$RecipeIngredientID'");

}
```

`$ingredient_name = mysql_query("UPDATE ...` - for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP `mysql_query` returns TRUE on success and FALSE on error. Not name or something else, boolean value only!

$Ingredient_ID in query must have same name as function argument, match all variables.